# Не получается запушить на github после filter-branch

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

Нужно удалить некоторые файлы из всех коммитов, использовал для этого

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f passwords.txt' HEAD
```

После этого сделал новый коммит, но при попытке запушить на github

```
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/xxx/xxx.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Как с таким нужно бороться или что нужно делать более правильно?

Comment: C репозиторием работаю только я, перед filter-branch локальный и удаленный не имели различий.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub очень бодро сканируется разными ботами в поисках паролей и ключей. Так что первое что вы должны сделать после того как опубликовали файл с паролями — сменить эти пароли. Если вы засветили их хоть на пять минут, считайте что показали их в рекламе по центральному ТВ, настолько же они небезопасны.

Команда `git filter-branch` переписывает историю Git. Теперь у вас и на гитхабе находятся разные ветви `master` и вы не можете просто так сделать `git push`.

Если и **только если** вы работаете с этим репозиторием в одиночку, можете переписать историю на гитхабе с помощью `git push --forced`. При этом `master` на гитхабе будет удален и заново скопирован с вашего. Все коммиты, которые существовали только в `github/master`, пропадут.

Если есть другие разработчики — вы таким образом устроите им незабываемые впечатления. Лучше просто сменить пароли и удалить файл в очередном коммите.